# Can any body tell me how to start the coding in the Cappuccino with the xcode?

Tags: cappuccino

Can any body tell how can i start to code in the Cappuccino in the xcode any tutorials or any good pdf that make me enough to start work with the xcode .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On the Cappuccino site, there's a place where you can download an installer that will add some Cappuccino templates to the standard Xcode template projects:  http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/getting-setup.php#editors

From there, you can choose File > New Project, and the Cappuccino templates should show up there in the New Project picker.

However, I don't believe the installer has been updated recently, so your mileage may vary.  =(

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://bit.ly/xwRdY) you can find the latest Xcode templates.

regards,
raphael

Answer (score 0):

I really would recommend that you go with Coda instead.

If you were interested in “taming” Xcode (it is not designed for Obj-J though), look into http://github.com/araxara/cappuccino/tree/Xcode/Tools/Editors/Xcode/.  However, it feels very wrong and Coda / TextMate can bid you extra productivity.